# unable to make arrow place properly for menu option

Tags: html, css

This is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mitchbregs/TVK4U/2/).

I want to make it so that the arrow goes to the right of the name, no matter how big the name is.

The arrow isn't being placed properly, and I have been struggling to figure it out.

I know it's super simple CSS, but I'm just having trouble with this one.

Thanks for all your answers!

```
#menu #container #right_menu_options #user span.arrow{
        border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        border-right: 4px solid transparent;
        border-top: 4px solid white;
        float: right;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 8px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TVK4U/3/)

CSS

```
#menu #container #right_menu_options #user span.arrow{
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    top: 17px;
}
#menu #container #right_menu_options #user p{
    margin-top: 9px;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 10px;       
}
```

Comment: oh man, its the simple. haha i feel stupid. thank you so much!

Comment: @Mitchell It's just position playing, and btw you can make your CSS far more better, some of the tips are to use `line-height` for `p` element instead of margins, and avoid using too much of id's if you are not using javascript